# Text shape animation, animating shape-outside

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-shapes

I am trying to achieve the following animation on the text of a paragraph :

[image: paragraph animation : changing the shape of the text]

The aim is to **animate the boundaries of the text** according to the shape on the left. This is what I have tried but I can't figure out the transition on the text shape :

```css
.mainDiv {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #e3f5f1;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.textElement {
  width: 395px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="textElement">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus Page Maker including versions of Lorem Ipsum, and more recently with desktop publishing software.
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't have much knowledge of *CSS* transitions and animations, so I hope to get some help.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Chrome & Fire Fox :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> **Disclaimer :** *The [shape-outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) property should not be used in live projects<sup>1</sup>. It may be subject to undesired behaviours.*

This kind of layout can be achieved with the by **animating the [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) and the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) properties**. Both properties can be transitioned to make the animation.

The drawback is that both have very low browser support and today, this animation will only work in webkit browsers as Firefox and IE/Edge don't support the [`shape-outside` property](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside) or the [`clip-path` property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) with a `polygon()` value.

Here is an example **(webkit only)** :

```css
.mainDiv{
  width:600px;
  margin:0px auto;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  padding:10px;
  min-height:200px;
}
.element{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#e3f5f1;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
  shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  transition: clip-path 1s, shape-outside 1s;
}
.mainDiv:hover .element {
  shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);  
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="element"></div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus Page Maker including versions of Lorem Ipsum, and more recently with desktop publishing software.
</div>
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>The [CSS Shapes Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/) currently (october 2016) has the status of "Candidate Recommendation". As this means it is a work in progress, it may change at any moment and therefore should not be used other than for testing.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @web-tiki...
Please let me know is there any other way to use this effect in firefox..

Comment: i like how only one line with unchanged width starts with "unchanged"

Answer (score 13):

### CSS

For this, you'll want to use some new and mostly unsupported elements in your CSS to achieve the effect you want.

These two elements are

- [`shape-outside`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes)
- [`clip-path`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Please note, this does not work on FF as requested but I reckon it won't be too far off.

```css
.mainDiv {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #e3f5f1;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  transition: shape-outside 1s, clip-path 1s, -webkit-clip-path 1s;
}
.element:hover {
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="textElement">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus Page Maker including versions of Lorem Ipsum, and more recently with desktop publishing software.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### SVG

The best way to guarantee that your page works across all browsers would probably be to use an SVG. This is the sort of animation you're looking for.

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="20%">
  <path id="square" d="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100z" fill="#e3f5f1">
    <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" begin="mouseover" dur="1s" to="M0,0 L100,50 L100,50 L0,100z" fill="freeze" />
    <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" begin="mouseout" dur="1s" to="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100z" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's not supporting firefox, can you please fix it...
I want to implement this effect on my site on blog section...

Comment: I did make a note in my answer saying this isn't supported in FF. You will have to opt for a SVG alternative which i will write up soon.

Comment: I don't have any idea about SVG... so how can i implement :(